# Variable DC to constant DC using Arduino Microcontroller

Tags: arduino

I am running a DC motor with the help of induction machine which gives me DC voltage at the output. If I change the speed of the induction machine, the DC voltage would change. What I wish to do is that no matter the DC voltage we get at the output, I need to have constant DC voltage. I am trying to implement it using arduino by changing the duty cycle. Any suggestions on how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: [EE SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely an EE question. To get a constant DC voltage from a PWM source, you should implement a low-pass R-C filter that will smoothen the PWM signal into an almost continous signal. You should put that filter between the µc and the base of the transistor powering your DC motor.

You can find online tutorials and courses on how to design such filters, but I'm not found of R-C filter calculations, and don't want to mislead you on the details. You can also ask on the [EE Q&A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) to get a better answer.

As an alternative, you can also find digipot components that you can control digitally using an I²C or 1-Wire bus.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

A lot of information concerning your question may be found in the Internet.
For example [here](http://www.circuitstoday.com/pwm-generation-and-control-using-arduino).
Here used Arduino together with PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) principles.